# Using String.Join in String Builder C#

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I am trying to create a csv string from a list of GUIDs (around 10000) of them. My snippet is below.

```
private string GetAppInformationForCache()
{
    StringBuilder appInfo = new ();
    var expiresString = $"Expires:{ExpirationDateTime:u};";

    appInfo.Append("1:" + string.Join(",", DefaultCatalogAppIds) + ";");
    appInfo.Append("L:" + string.Join(",", PrivateCatalogAppIds) + ";");
    appInfo.Append("3:" + string.Join(",", GlobalCatalogAppIds) + ";");
    appInfo.Append(expiresString);

    return appInfo.ToString();
}
```

This is in a high traffic API around 30K RPS. I am sure string.Join has some memory allocation concerns in such a high volume. I was asked to change this to a more performant implementation. I could not find a better way to do this except looping throught the guids and appending to resultant string builder.

Is there a more performant way to handle this?

Comment: Using string.join here essentially negates any performance improvement that the stringbuilder is giving you. If you need performance, generally manually looping values will be faster. Takes a little more work up front, but pays out with a few ms savings on the back-side. Also, if this is cached, it really shouldn't be that concerning either way.

Comment: can you please explain the last part? if this is cached? I didnt get it

Comment: @Nieminen There's a dedicated method equivalent to `string.Join` that OP can use. Manual looping is just more effort here.

Comment: @Nieminen - That's not true to say it "essentially negates any performance". `String.Join` is fast and using `StringBuilder` to put those parts together is still a huge saving.

Comment: @Enigmativity - I appreciate the comments, I was over-simplifying. I see someone posted an answer with `AppendJoin`, I haven't used that before, but seems like the best solution here. @Programmerzzz what I meant by 'cached', is the method you posted is called 'GetAppInformationForCache'... From the naming convention I only assume the result is cached based on the expiration date time. If this is indeed cached, it'll only be executed once per lifetime of the cache.

Comment: You should also do `appInfo.AppendFormat("Expires:{0:u};", ExpirationDateTime);`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`AppendJoin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.appendjoin?view=net-7.0):

```
appInfo.Append("1:");
appInfo.AppendJoin(",", DefaultCatalogAppIds);
appInfo.Append(";");
```

And so on.

Comment: can you please explain how this is better than what I have now?

Comment: @Programmerzzz `string.Join` constructs a string, interns it, and then adds it to the StringBuilder as a whole string.  `AppendJoin` appends the individual parts instead of first constructing a big string. It's roughly similar to why `StringBuilder` is considered more efficient than `string.Concat` or `string + string`.

Comment: While I was having a walk, I realised that my comment might be misinterpreted. I don't want to say that `string.Join` is as inefficient as `string + string` can be, rather that with `AppendJoin` you're not building a big string, only to incorporate it into a bigger string, so you're cutting out a small part of it by skipping that and going directly to `AppendJoin`.  It's also just easier to read because there's less going on.

Comment: To be fair, `StringBuilder` is slower than `String.Concat` or `string + string` when the concatenation is done once. It is only beneficial when you are repeatedly concatenating strings.

Comment: @Enigmativity That's true. I guess it's like a lot of things where X is more efficient than Y until N reaches a large enough number and then Y becomes the more efficient one.